# Are ElasticSearch document IDs scored?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

If the mapping of a document is set to analyzed, it's scored and then relevant results are returned on a query. Are document IDs (_id) scored too?
I need to perform an exact ID match on a analyzed document and cannot change the type to non-analyzed since I'm unable to dump the data already in that index.
Will making a query with a specific ID return the exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document ID's are not scored in elasticsearch.

So `index/type/id` will fetch the exact document with given `id`

From docs:

> Each document indexed is associated with a _type (see the section
>   called “Mapping Typesedit”) and an _id. The _id field is not indexed.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks a lot!